# How to use a Integer from another method

Tags: java, variables, methods, binary, extends

```
package BinaryCode;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        calculations();

    }

    public static int calculations(){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your binary");

        int binary = scan.nextInt();
        int shift = 0;
        int dec = 0;
        int rest = 0;

        while(binary!= 0){

            rest = binary%10;
            dec = dec+(int)(rest*(Math.pow(2, shift)));
            binary = binary/10;
            shift = shift+1;

        }

        System.out.println(dec);

        return binary;
    }
    public static void length (){

        int length = String.valueOf(binary);

    }


}
```

So I am a beginner and I tried to program a converter that converts binary code to a decimal number. That worked well now I want to limit the length of the binary number, but I cannot access the int binary in another method. If I put it in the main method, there is also no access. Outside of all methods, in the class I somehow can't save any changes(if the value changes). I would greatly appreciate any help and I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: To "use an integer from another method" you need to pass the integer as a function/method argument. The easiest way is to declare length as `public static void length(int binary)` then call it from`calculations` with `length(binary)`. Note, you'll likely want to return a value from your `length` method since it doesn't really do anything as it is. Also, `String.valueOf` returns a string and not an `int`.

Comment: You have a few issues with your code. Note that even though you may enter binary into `scan.nextInt()`, the entered data is already in base10 decimal form, since that is how `nextInt()` is interpreting the entered data. That said, it isn't clear what you are actually trying to do. Can you please provide example input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

> but I cannot access the int binary in another method.

Because it does not exist.

'binary' is declared as local in the `calculations' method. It ceases to exist when that method returns.

The fact that you can't mention its name outside the method reflects its non-existence outside the method; the technical term is 'scope'.

If you want 'binary' to have a lifetime beyond the method, you could declare it as a class or instance variable.  Add

```
static int binary;
```

outside any method, and turn the existing declaration of binary into a simple assignment.

```
binary = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: This is true, but I think it is useful for the OP to understand how to pass `binary` as a function argument, since in this use case there really isn't a need for static variables, and just making variables static/global is often not the best implementation.

Comment: I agree on the issue; my thought was to introduce 'least change from current code', and also help along the notion of scope.  I'm not saying you're wrong, just that there are multiple paths.